# Determine whether $h: A → \mathbb{C}$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A =\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\\\end{pmatrix}: a,b \in R\},$ which is a subset of the ring $M_2( \mathbb R)$. Define $h:A→\mathbb{C}$ by $h\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\\\end{pmatrix}=a+bi$, $\forall \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\\\end{pmatrix} \in A$

1. Determine whether $h: A → \mathbb{C}$ is a ring homomorphism.
2. Determine whether $h: A → \mathbb{C}$ is a ring isomorphism.

**My Attempt:** (finally figured out 1)

1. $h\begin{pmatrix}a+c & b+d\\-b-d & a+c\\\end{pmatrix} = (a+c)+(b+d)i$
   $h\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\\\end{pmatrix} + h\begin{pmatrix}c & d\\-d & c\\\end{pmatrix} = (a+bi)+(c+di) = (a+c)+(c+d)i$

$h\begin{pmatrix}ac-bd & bc+ad\\-(bc+ad) & ac-bd\\\end{pmatrix} =(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$  and $h\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\\\end{pmatrix}*h\begin{pmatrix}c & d\\-d & c\\\end{pmatrix}=(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$.

**Edit** I can see $h$ is surjective, but I am still confused on how to verify whether or not $h$ is injective?

Comment: Your post is filled with strange characters.

Comment: They are called matrices, it's pretty standard in maths. ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not seeing anything strange!

Comment: For example "" might show up as one thing to you, but to me it just shows up as a white rectangle with a black border.

Comment: The strange characters are all from Unicode's "Supplementary Private Use Area B". Whatever they show up as for the OP, he has no good reason to expect that the rest of us will see the same thing. Are you trying to use tengwar as variable letters or what?

Comment: I am not trying to use anything. I am new here and typing my best as I can. I didn't even copy and paste anything just to make sure nothing makes difficult for the readers. Why would you commented such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for 1 the multiplication structure on $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ is given by matrix multiplication, so what you need to check is if h(AB)=h(A)h(B), with AB normal matrix multiplication.

If you have finished 1, for 2 you should check whether h is injective and surjective. Concretely $\forall c\in \mathbb{C}$ is there a $m \in M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $h(m) = c$ (surjectivity), and does $h(c) = 0 \implies c = 0$ (injectivity).